# Custom request header for Iframe/web page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to display an iframe that requires a custom header to authenticate. Its a display signage software that supports html code/ url loading/or custom webpages.

I've been looking into options and seems possible with js. can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible per se.

You can set custom headers when making a request using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, but not when making a request with any other kind of originator.

The closest you could come would be to make the request with one of the above, and then populate the iframe with the response (but that would likely break any relative URLs in it).

Comment: okay so not inside and iframe then. Could it be done as an html page?

Comment: @iamthedj – That doesn't really make sense. iframe is to HTML page as road is to car. They aren't alternatives to each other.